# Curl Command PUT Method

Tags: ubuntu, curl

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Length: 1000' http://dfdc:dfdc@xx.xx.xx.xxx:xx/directory/
```

Above curl doesn't produce any response at Ubuntu shell prompt.

Comment: And your question is, “Why?”

Answer (score 1):

First: 
If I try this, the command does not return at all.

Calling curl with -v to get some more verbose output, I can see, that the PUT is sent, but the server sits and waits for more to come. This is because you gave "Content-Length: 1000" without giving any content.

If you omit this header, you get a response.

Second: 
What are you PUTting? As with POST you should give some data with --data or -d

i.e.

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Length: 1000' -d "@somefile" http://dfdc:dfdc@xx.xx.xx.xxx:xx/directory/
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If you're going to downvote, at least comment. This is exactly what I would have suggested.